# Run code every time a route within a specific sub-directory is hit NextJS

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js

I'm new to NextJS.
Is it possible to run client side code for every sub-route in an app? I want to be able to check if a user is authenticated every time they hit a route in the `/admin` directory.

I'm using firebase for authentication so this would have to be done client side after the `auth.currentUser` object has been populated. I mention this as I'm aware of next12's middleware functionality, correct me if I'm wrong but I don't think it would fit this use case.

Comment: What is the scope of `auth` object? Is it in the context or some other common store?

Comment: @TusharShahi it's exported from a file at the root of the project.

Comment: You probably need context, but if it is just a variable why not use it in middleware?